# Can a var be a key in a map?

Tags: dictionary, clojure

```
(def nextStudentNumber 1000)

(defn s
  [lastName firstName]
  (let [student {:nextStudentNumber {:lastName lastName
                                     :firstName firstName
                                     :grades {}
                                     :id (inc nextStudentNumber)}}]
```

In this instance, I have created the var `nextStudentNumber` and I want to have map that keys that change on the of the student.

Comment: Maybe it's only me, but it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: nextStudentNumber should be an atom otherwise every student will have the same id

Comment: Though not a direct answer to your question, I asked a similar "cousin" question a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937495/how-to-access-a-value-using-a-space-separated-key It might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like any object a var can be a key in a map:

```
{#'foo 42}
=> {#'user/foo 42}
```

Since that won't help you, here is an example construct for your question:

```
(->> [{:name "Mara"} {:name "Lara"} {:name "Clara"}]
     (map-indexed #(assoc %2 :id %1)) ;; assign an ID to each student
     (group-by :id)) ;; Create a hash-map where students can be looked up by ID
=> {0 [{:name "Mara, :id 0}], 1 [{:name "Lara", :id 1}]
    2 [{:name "Clara", :id 2}]}
```

Notice that this example is a bit redundant (as index lookup can be performed in a vector directly by invoking it with the index).

However, it shows the basic idea of working with immutable data: In independent steps you generate IDs and do grouping. You can compose such steps in many ways, like generating IDs for new students, adding them to a collection of existing students and grouping them by ID. Notice that the `(group-by :id)` step works independently of how the IDs are generated and tolerates scenarios where two students have the same ID which you can then detect and handle.

The imperative approach is very untypical in functional Clojure world. If you have many functions that allocate students (and in your thinking should invoke `s`), rather make them pure and let them return collections of students and give them names like `load-students-from-file`, `generate-ids` and use constructs like `concat`, `into` to combine collections returned by them without the need to mess with state, until you do I/O with the student data.

If, out of curiosity, you still want to mess with state, here is another (rather unidiomatic) code-sample:

```
(def student-count (atom 0))
(def students-by-id (atom {}))

(defn add-student! [first-name last-name]
   (let [next-id (swap! student-count inc)]
     (swap! students-by-id
            assoc next-id {:first-name first-name, :last-name last-name
                           :id next-id})))
```

E. g.:

```
(add-student! "Mara" "Mad")
(add-student! "Lara" "Light")
(@students-by-id 1)
=> {:first-name "Lara", :last-name "Light", :id 1}
```

As you can see, everything is complected in one step here.

Answer (score 0):

```
{:nextStudentNumber {:lastName lastName
                     :firstName firstName
                     :grades {}
                     :id (inc nextStudentNumber)}
```

I assume you want this transformed into something like:

```
{:1000 {:lastName lastName
        :firstName firstName
        :grades {}
        :id (inc nextStudentNumber)}
```

in which case you'll want:

```
{(keyword (str nextStudentNumber)) {:lastName lastName
                                    :firstName firstName
                                    :grades {}
                                    :id (inc nextStudentNumber)}
```

There are some other smelly things like camel case and `inc`. We use levitating snake in clojure so `lastName` would be `last-name`. I don't know what you're doing with `inc` but it's giving off heavy imperative vibes.

Comment: inc does not change the var, so every student would have the same :id