# Clojure list/set state example

Tags: list, clojure, state

And here's me thinking that I understand FP at all!

Can anybody provide me with a Clojure example of a set or list function, maintaining state, please.

In the example that I've been working on, I want a power object (I guess, a set or a list) to which I can add or remove a component.

I then want the internal behaviour of the component object to be affected by whether or not it has power (i.e. is stored by the power object).

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please add details/examples.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're after, but Clojure's built-in data structures are persistent and explicitly avoid state. Adding/removing an item to/from a set doesn't modify the state of that set, it creates a new set.

Comment: I am trying to simulate real-world objects, using Clojure functions. Imagine I plug in a television object. I want to register the t.v. with a power function, reflecting that the t.v. is receiving power.  The t.v. object would report that it is 'on', when it is found in the power list.  If, as you say, a new power list is created, isn't that a new and different object?

Comment: afro54: what you are talking about is not functional programming

Comment: I think that it absolutely is but, to clarify, I am approaching this from an OO perspective. I am investigating how Clojure functions might represent and efficiently model independent, interacting, real-world things. To that end, a power-source, a switch, and a component device. It's Clojure as a DSL. Now that I re-read it, it's akin to MVC, in Clojure functions.

Comment: There goes stack overflow again - cancelling my questions!  Well, the joke's on you, this time.  I actually got my answer, before you squashed the question! Mutable state, immutable identity.  Thanks, all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are not the best way to simulate objects, they are a better fit for simulating processes. When using Clojure the best way to organize your code is thinking about the data you need to handle and also about the operations you want applied to that data. There **are** ways of simulating object (as in OOP) behavior using closures on data and such, but I think that if you are using a functional language it's better not to try to fit a square peg in a round hole.

So... assuming your components are maps or records, what you can do is modify the way a function handles an instance of a component based on their value (i.e. `{,,, :power true}`). One way to do this is having a single plain function that checks the `:power` of your component and decides what to do:

```
(defn check-power [x]
  (if (:power x)
    (prn "This thing is working.")
    (prn "Might want to power this on.")))
```

Another approach that allows you to isolate each implementation would be using [multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods):

```
(defmulti check-power
  :power)

(defmethod check-power true
  [x]
  (prn "This thing is working."))

(defmethod check-power false
  [x]
  (prn "Might want to power this on."))

(check-power {:power true})
```

Keeping the `power` state of your components in a global var (with an atom for example) might not be the best approach since:

1. Now you need to remember to maintain the set or list that defines your components' power.
2. It makes your code less obvious to the reader.
3. When you are developing at the REPL you might leave the state of your `power` var out of sync with the rest of the code.

---

Data structures in Clojure are immutable, so every time you "modify" something what you get is a new object with the modification done. This changes the way you should think about how to structure your code, data flows through a series of functions that modify it, so that in the end you have the result you are looking for.

```
x -> f -> g -> .... -> h -> x'
```

As you can see there's no "place" where the data is kept here, just an initial state, a bunch of operations on it and a final state. But I guess if all applications could be expressed in these terms we would be out of a job.

Things get a little more complicated when you depend on user input to decide what to do with your data or you just simply need to hold on to your state until an event happens, because now you have to keep it somewhere (a "place") that's what reference types are for (i.e. `var`, `ref`, `atom` and `agent`).

In your case, based on the information we have, I guess you could keep all of your components in a `set` and pass it around the functions that need to operate on your components collection.

So the way you would use a `toggle-power` function in the way I've described is the following:

```
(defn toggle-power
  [x]
  (assoc x :power (not (:power x))))

(defn toggle-power-all [components]
  (reduce #(conj %1 (toggle-power %2)) #{} components))

(defn build-components []
  #{{:id 1 :power false}
    {:id 2 :power true}
    {:id 3 :power false}})

(defn -main []
  (let [components (build-components)]
    (-> components
      toggle-power-all
      ;; do more stuff here
      toggle-power-all)))

(-main)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your replies but, doesn't :power acquire mutable state, by way of the items in its map? If the reference to :power is unchanged (for other functions), aren't its map items reflecting currently powered components?

Comment: @afro54 Just updated the answer adding a more extended discussion on Clojure and how to structure your code. It's stuff we all had to learn the hard way, making mistakes and thinking about the problem, maybe others might have a different view of things, this is mine.

Comment: I should go away and read some more, instead of all the questions. Regarding your 3 points about the use of atom. Part of my object approach means that I would have a relay component, whose sole job it is to manage the power set. On point 2 isn't it more obvious to the stakeholder, to consider a power function in this way? On point 3, my misunderstanding is that an atom reference for the power function would be all that is available to other functions. In that way, the power function is solely responsible for reporting the state of added components to the system. Thoughts?

Comment: @afro54: I think you're still thinking too much from an object-oriented angle. In functional programming, we're stepping back and thinking about what things *are*, and what functions *do*, not the state of mutable data. In a way, object-oriented programming actually complicates things by forcing you to think about the state of variables. Once you spend some time learning how to do functional programming in general, something will click in your brain and you'll wonder why you ever preferred the object-oriented model. Functional programming is just simpler.

Comment: FP is functional - problem and solution, task-over-process. I modelled a couple of objects in Clojure, which is a good thing and the requirement. lgrapenthin's example worked perfectly. With add-watch in a component function, the t.v. function can be aware of a state-change in 'power'.  Better still, Instead of add-watch, I could use of 'power' as a first-order function, within the component function. OO forces us to consider the state of objects, not variables, as part of their function/behaviour. This delivers objects that remain both loosely-coupled and highly cohesive. Job (nearly) done!

Comment: I appreciate everybody's comments, and it has helped to clarify (and reinforce) my approach.  I would disagree with your last sentence, though, on the basis that FP is not an alternative to the OO model - it is a tool for implementing what you wish, which might be OO-based. The click in my brain was in realising this. The previous click was in realising that Java, as an OO language, is totally ill-equipped to discharge the responsibility of simulating an OO model.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure's set and list datatypes maintain state in that they are immutable and their state cannot be changed*.

The right way to do mutation in Clojure is to either use a `ref` or `atom` that can be updated to point at a new Object, or (in narrow performance driven circumstances) use mutable Java datatypes via interop.

The idea of your data changing in behavior based on the container it resides inside is incompatible with functional programming. You can probably do it with Java interop by defining a class, but frankly if you want a design like this, you aren't doing functional programming and trying to use Clojure is going to provide very little benefit, you'll likely be fighting the design of the language every step of the way.

That said, the task you have in mind does not require mutable sets or mutable lists**, and there is much to gain by and learn from using Clojure's immutable functional ecosystem.

Maintaining a "mutable set" with an atom:

```
user> (def s (atom #{}))
#'user/s
user> (swap! s conj :a)
#{:a}
user> (def s' @s)
#'user/s'
user> s'
#{:a}
user> (swap! s conj :b)
#{:a :b}
user> @s
#{:a :b}
user> s'
#{:a}
user> (swap! s disj :a)
#{:b}
user> @s
#{:b}
user> s'
#{:a}
```

note that changing `s` did not change `s'`, the sets were never altered, only the atom itself.

A "mutable list":

```
user> (def l (atom (list)))
#'user/l
user> (swap! l conj :a)
(:a)
user> (swap! l conj :b)
(:b :a)
user> (swap! l conj :a)
(:a :b :a)
user> (swap! l rest)
(:b :a)
user> (swap! l rest)
(:a)
user> l
#<Atom@31c3f99f: (:a)>
user> @l
(:a)
user>
```

(*) Technically, you can mess with the implementation methods and mutate an "immutable" object in some circumstances. You should not do this.

(**) Of course, on some level in the VM the immutability of Clojure is transformed (safely) into mutable actions in a stack machine. The difference with semantic immutibility is that the programmer does not have to worry about mutation or its consequences.

Comment: I wonder if I'm after mutable objects! What are they? These examples work for me, so far. I want a function whose result will be conditional upon existing in the list of another function. If that's a mutable object, I want one!

Answer (score 0):

```
(def power-object (atom #{}))
(defn has-power? [obj] (contains? @power-object obj))
(defn give-power [obj] (swap! power-object conj obj))
```

EDIT: Forgot

```
(defn remove-power [obj] (swap! power-object disj obj))
```

Comment: I'm thinking that this is the money! I'd suspected atom, ref, etc. I clouded my thinking at some point but, I shall attack my problem, using this method.  Are there problems ahead, in the general use of atoms?

Comment: Yes. Many. I can hardly recommend you any datastructures since the idea of a power-object is very general. Preferably, don't use any atoms, rather pass the set with the empowered objects around and only transform it via pure functions. Omit functions like has-power and rather use idioms like `(contains? power-objects obj)` directly. Also refer to my more extensive answer to a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287536/can-a-var-be-a-key-in-a-map/22289544#22289544

Comment: If you really, really need state, an atom would still be the way to go. If you need coordinated synchronous access, use a ref. Make sure however that you don't have the atom in a top-level def, because global state will mess badly with you at some point. Prefer encapsulated state e. g. with Stuart Sierras lib component http://www.github.com/stuartsierra/component

Comment: Also since you mentioned to make internal behavior of objects depending on whether they have "power", it would probably be better not to have one power object but to assign their power-state individually.

Comment: Thanks for all of the good info. Instantly disagree with your last comment, from my OO POV and approach. I need loose-coupling between objects/functions. It is important that a component is not responsible for its own power/state, just its behaviour.  Great call with the github link, though!

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, as is likely. The model, that I want to describe in Clojure, has a component/function called relay.  Its on/off method will be your give-power/remove-power, judging by the response I get in Light Table! My (our) next trick is to make relay list components it considers 'on', independently of components in power-object.

Comment: I didn't say that the component needs to be responsible about it's power state. I just say it would probably not be a good idea to store that state globally, /especially/ if you are interested in loose coupling. - Because no matter whether it's in an atom or an immutable value: You need two things to obtain complete information about one thing.

Comment: I don't understand where I have stored state globally, beyond the power-object, which is the requirement. That two things interact to provide complete information reflects the real-world, in exactly the way that I need. It's at least half the point of this exercise. I'd appreciate any pointers regarding top-level def and global state, though.

Comment: Right, I may have misinterpreted your approach. It's difficult to imagine the concept of a power object with empowered objects without any real world scenario where it might be applicable (I might have to add that I also don't know a lot about LightTable, I don't really understand your relay example :() I just don't want to point you at a direction where you end up suffering from complection later. Notice that stateful interaction requires coordination at some point in time - Have you researched core.async considering your case?

Comment: Light Table is just a REPL and IDE that I use. core.async does figure in my future plans. Before that, I need to model an electrical circuit.  A lightbulb (empowered object) will exhibit behaviour when a switch (relay) enables the power supply (power object). My next trick is to pass and evaluate function names, instead of :individuals, between functions.